# Как написать регулярное выражение для удаления последней директории из строки?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть куча строк такого типа:

```
https://domain.com/tags/js/
https://domain.com/dir/negotiations/chi
https://domain.com/ask/parent/quest/pr/
```

Как написать регулярное выражение, чтобы у всех строк обрезать последнюю директорию?

Проблема в том, что строка может заканчиваться слешем, а может быть и без него. И также в каждой строке разное количество директорий.

То есть нужно получить такие строки:

```
https://domain.com/tags/
https://domain.com/dir/negotiations/
https://domain.com/ask/parent/quest/
```

Comment: [`^.+\/(?=[^\/]+\/?$)`](https://regex101.com/r/Yru59w/1)

Comment: для замены именно `[^\/]*\/?$` достаточно на пустую строку